# Join three Tables without a common ID #MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 tables cam_details, cam_category and upload_data as following..

cam_details:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------
| cam_id | category_id| cam_name |
+========+============+===========
| 1      |  1         | CCTV     |
+--------+------------+-----------
| 2      |  1         | CCtv2    |
+--------+------------+===========
| 3      |  2         | cctv3    |
+--------+------------+=========== 
| 4      |  4         | cctv4    |
+--------+------------+===========
```

cam_category:

```
+-------------+---------------+
| category_id | category_name |
+=============+===============+
| 1           |  Analog       | 
+-------------+---------------+
| 2           |  Digital      |
+-------------+---------------+
| 3           |  Network      | 
+-------------+---------------+  
| 4           |  Simple       | 
+-------------+---------------+
```

upload_data:

```
+---------+-----------+
| cam_id  | FILE_NAME |
+========+============+
| 1      |  abc.jpg   | 
+--------+------------+
| 1      |  abc2.jpg  |
+--------+------------+
| 1      |  abc3.jpg  | 
+--------+------------+  
| 2      |  xyz.jpg   | 
+--------+------------+
```

now i want to fetch the details of the cam in a array and display the results. i am able to fetch cam pic and cam_details but not the cam_category name.
code below...

```
<?php
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT cam_details.*, upload_data.FILE_NAME FROM `cam_details` 
 JOIN  upload_data on cam_details.cam_id = upload_data.cam_id LEFT JOIN cam_category c
    on cam_details.category_id = c.category_id 
    GROUP BY upload_data.cam_id ORDER BY cam_id DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{?>
```

Comment: That's because you don't select it at all. You select everything from `cam_details` and `FILE_NAME ` from `upload_data` - that's it. There's no selection of anything from the `cam_category` table. You want something like `SELECT cam_details.*, upload_data.FILE_NAME, cam_category.category_name FROM....` instead.

Comment: didnt work @Qirel

Comment: shouldn't you use cam_details.categoryID instead of cam_details.category_id?

Comment: Well spotted, @HansGerber!

Comment: sorry for that mistake i always use same name in the column by mistake didn't edit that :( @HansGerber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of left join do only join and use selec command at first for the cateroy table...

```
<?php
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT cam_details.*, upload_data.FILE_NAME, cam_category.*  FROM `cam_details` 
 JOIN  upload_data on cam_details.cam_id = upload_data.cam_id JOIN cam_category 
     on cam_details.category_id = cam_category.category_id 
    GROUP BY upload_data.cam_id ORDER BY cam_id DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{?>
```

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause but no aggregate functions. Alarm bells should start ringing. And it most certainly doesn't 'work fine'

Comment: sorry for late response what is aggerate function? i used group bcoz one cam_id have multiple pictures @Strawberry